# How can I use the same filters to filter two duplicate columns seperately?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a  table visualization in Power BI with two columns **QuaterYear and SalesAmountB.** I want to add another column  **SalesAmountB**.

I have two filters (QuaterYear - case 1 and Quater Year Case 2] for the same field 'QuaterYear'.

As per my requirement, I need the filters QuaterYear - case 1 and QuaterYear - case 2 to filter these two duplicate columns SalesAmountB separately. The first filter should filter salesamount B column separate and the second filter should filter SalesamoutB separate. But when I select the QuaterYear - Case 1, the same selection comes preselected in QuaterYear-Case 2. I understand it's logical but is there a way using some calculations or parameters I can handle such a scenario?

At moment a selection in the first filter Quater-Case1 is preselecting Quater-Case2 filter by default.

**Expected Output**

I want Quater-Case 1 selection should let me choose column SalesAmountB separately and Quater-Case2 should let me choose column SalesAmount B separately though both columns are from the same and from the same table. Could you please suggest any approach or calculation [DAX] to handle this?

**My present visualizaion**

[image: My present table visual with filters]

Input data source excel:**

```
QuaterYear Salesamount  Place
Q12017  1000           London
Q12017  1100           London
Q12017  1120           London
Q12017  900            Tokyo
Q22017  2200           Tokyo
Q22017  2100           Tokyo
Q22017  1000           Tokyo
Q22017  500            Tokyo
Q22017  1900           Tokyo
Q22017  1900           Tokyo
Q22017  2000           Tokyo
Q22017  4000           Tokyo
Q22017  2100           Tokyo
Q32017  1100           Singapore
Q32017  890            Singapore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you don't need a duplicated sales column but you do need two separate independent parameter tables to use for the quarter selection.

For example, two separate calculated tables to use as slicers:

```
Case1 = VALUES ( Data[QuarterYear] )
```

```
Case2 = VALUES ( Data[QuarterYear] )
```

Then two separate measures that read the slicers.

```
SalesAmountA =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Data[SalesAmount] ),
    Data[QuarterYear] IN VALUES ( Case1[QuarterYear] )
)
```

```
SalesAmountB =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Data[SalesAmount] ),
    Data[QuarterYear] IN VALUES ( Case2[QuarterYear] )
)
```

Setting it up this way, the slicers won't affect each other since they are on separate columns from separate tables with no relationship to your original table.

Comment: Thankyou very much, yes i think this works..I will keep the thread open to see some more scenarios.But Alexis you rock, i was really not able to understand this concept of independent filter

Comment: also Alexis could you please tell me if after selecting the filter values, I need to find percent difference between salesAmountA - SalesAmountB columns and save it in another column say Difference, can i perform it by creating a measure %Difference= [salesAmountA] - [salesAmountB] *100/[salesAmountA]?I tried it now but I am getting 0% for all my selections.Please suggest if something I did wrong.

Comment: My bad , please ignore the above question ,I was using calculated column instead of measure to find the difference in values of columns